# I have a copy of Microsoft Dynamics POS 2009. How do I extend it or make add-ins?

Tags: add-in, microsoft-dynamics

I have a copy of Microsoft Dynamics POS 2009. How do I extend it or make add-ins?

I've been trying to search the net for the answer to this question, but I'm not turning up with anything.

Is there a project type I can install into Visual Studio or something like that?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Microsoft+Dynamics+POS+2009&oq=Microsoft+Dynamics+POS+2009#q=%22Microsoft+Dynamics+POS+2009%22) help?

Comment: Also, see from "[Mainstream support for Microsoft Dynamics POS 2009](https://community.dynamics.com/rms/b/rmssupport/archive/2014/03/04/mainstream-support-for-microsoft-dynamics-pos-2009.aspx)" that mainstream support for Dynamics POS 2009 ended in June 2014.

Comment: See also https://community.dynamics.com/rms/f/106/t/75223.aspx. You can probably find the rest on your own.

Comment: I googled for `Microsoft Dynamics POS addin site:microsoft.com` and found a ton of links... what search terms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised at how hard it was to find the SDK for this product. It's only available to Microsoft Dynamics Registered Partners.

John Saunders' third comment includes one of the only places I found with links to the SDK. The page at the following link also includes a link to the SDK update for POS 2009 SP1: http://www.microsoftdynamicsforums.com/forums/forum_posts.asp?TID=4067&title=pos-2009-sdk-where-is-it

There isn't a link to the SDK available through the Microsoft.com search field, but they do have a link to the data model, which may be helpful:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/975368

I assume that someone down-voted the question because "Justin should have Googled it," but the fact is... Google didn't help. The search that John Saunders posted in the first comment does not lead to the SDK within the first ten pages of results. (This Stackoverflow question showed up on the third page of results!) Those ten pages had around twenty links to cracks and keygens. There were references in ancient news releases about the product that trumpeted the SDK -- but even searching for [dynamics 2009 sdk] the closest I could find were links where someone took pity on a searcher, as John Saunders did. Well, I did find a post from 2011 where someone offered to pay $100 for a copy of the SDK. The links that Lynn Crumbling found by restricting the search to Microsoft.com are misleading on the surface. On the first four pages, all but one are links to other Dynamics products, and even that one is an owner of POS 2009 asking for the SDK. The response referred the owner to the same forum that John Saunder's linked to, but not to any specific post.

Comment: Thanks for the post and links. I found them helpful. My MSDN subscription gave me access to the software, but unfortunately I'm not a Microsoft Dynamics Registered Partner and can't download the SDK. Looks like I'm stuck. But, I do thank you for your help.